# How do I put COALESCE inside a CASE WHEN statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to apply a case when to my coalesce

This is what I've tried so far

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(t1.disbursedAmount, t2.PLMdisbursedAmount) Dispursed_Amount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Dispursed_Amount END AS Dispursed_Amount
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a dangling alias or column reference.  This is the syntax:

```
(CASE WHEN COALESCE(t1.disbursedAmount, t2.PLMdisbursedAmount) IS NULL 
      THEN 0
      ELSE COALESCE(t1.disbursedAmount, t2.PLMdisbursedAmount)
 END) AS Dispursed_Amount
```

Of course, that is needlessly complex.  You can just use:

```
COALESCE(t1.disbursedAmount, t2.PLMdisbursedAmount, 0)
```